# I can be personal

Tags: riddle

> I can be personal
>   or a commercial
>   but for spreading the
>   information and thoughts.
>   
>   Remove the first character
>   and you will find me
>   on the web server or
>   under the tree.
>   
>   Don't think to remove
>   the second character
>   as I can be
>   dangerous for you.
>   
>   Replace the last
>   a character from first
>   and then you can
>   spot me easily.

What  I am?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thought is that you are a

> blog

I can be personal or a commercial but for spreading the information and thoughts.

> A company or person may write a web blog to publish their thoughts.

Remove the first character and you will find me on the web server or under the tree.

> An event log on a  server,  or a wooden log perhaps broken off the tree.

Don't think to remove the second character as I can be dangerous for you.

> A bog is wet ground where you may get stuck or swallowed up!

Replace the last a character from first and then you can spot me easily.

> A **b**lo**b** - in astronomy a huge body of gas, or in general a shapeless mass, or a blob of colour.

Comment: very quick and correct. I am assuming the blob - a spot of colour though. Anyway i accept the answer. cheers!

Comment: Thanks Anurag for creating this nice riddle - and I learned more about differences in [wet ground](http://www.ponderweasel.com/the-difference-between-a-marsh-swamp-bog-and-fen/) too!